# How to write a wrapper that keeps rapping the output?

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

Basically, what I want to do is to hava a wrapper on some abstract class, then have the same wrapper class wrap around the output of any member function of that class. Keep doing that so that all objects are always wrapped.

Like (presudocode)

```
wrap<set(1..10)> (multiply,2)
                 (divide,3)
                 (plus,5)
                 (inverse)
                 (collect first 10)
                .unwrap()
```

All lines above except the last line outputs wrap of something. It seems to be meanling less for now, but I believe then we can apply interesting things on it like:

```
wrap<someClass> dat;
dat.splitIntoThreads(2)
    (thingA)    .clone()
    (thingB)    (thing1)
    (thingC)    (thing2)
    (thingD)    (thing3)
    .nothing()  (thing4)
    .sync()     .exit()
    .addMerge()
```

Here is my code for wrap:

```
template<class T>
struct wrap{
  wrap(){}
  wrap(T b){a=b;}
  template<class L,class...R>
  L operator() (L(T::*f)(R...),R...r){
    return a.f(r...);
  }
  T a;
};

int main(){
  wrap<testClass> a;
  a(&testClass::f,13,'a');
}
```

It's working (gcc, c++0x). But when I replace the 6,7th line with the following (to actually wrap the result)

```
wrap<L> operator() (L(T::*f)(R...),R...r){
  return wrap<L>(a.f(r...));
```

The compiler just sais: creating pointer to member function of non-class type "int".

How can I fix this? Is there any better to do this? Inheritence is one way but since we might have variable instance in one wrap, I think it's not useful.

**EDIT**

Here's my test class

```
struct testClass{
  int f(int a,char b){
    return a+b;
  }
};
```

The reason why I'm using wrap L instead of wrap T is that the return type might not always be T.

Comment: Don't you need a.*f instead of a.f ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I remember that function pointer will be treated just like function and the a.f in working code works

Comment: How is your `testclass` definition? Can you give us a snippet? I tried to emulate your wrap. http://cpp.sh/8at6z This seems to work. I think the error is your definition of `testclass`.   `return wrap<L>(a.f(r...));` works completely fine for me.

Comment: Problem is when you want to create `wrap<fundamental type>` ex. `wrap<int>` as there can't be a pointer to `int` method. `T::*f` will expand to `int::*f` or compiler think so ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, bool = false>
struct wrap{
  template <typename... Args>
  wrap(Args&&... args) : a{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {};
  template<class L, class...R>
  wrap<L,std::is_fundamental<L>::value> operator() (L(T::*f)(R...),R...r){
    return wrap<L,std::is_fundamental<L>::value > {(a.*f)(r...)};
  }
  T a;
};

template<class T>
struct wrap <T,true>{
  template <typename... Args>
  wrap(Args&&... args) : a{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
  template<class L, class...R>
  wrap<L,std::is_fundamental<L>::value> operator() (L(*f)(T a, R...), R...r){
      return wrap<L,std::is_fundamental<L>::value > {f(a, r...)};
  }
  T a;
};

class testClass {
    int m;
public:
testClass(int _m) : m{_m}{}
    int multiAdd(int x, char y) {
        m += x + y;
        return m;
    }
};

int add(int a, char b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main(){
  wrap<testClass> a{0};
  std::cout << a(&testClass::multiAdd,0,'d')(add,'a').a<<std::endl;

  wrap<int, true> b{3};
  std::cout << b(add,'a').a<<std::endl;
}
```

[cpp.sh/6icg](http://cpp.sh/6icg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is in your `testclass` definition. Please check the below example.

Also, wrap in the operator() can be returned as reference. I don't see any need to create temporaries to be used for () chaining.

```
template<class T>
struct wrap{
  template <typename... Args>
  wrap(Args&&... args) : a{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {};

  template<class L, class...R>
  wrap<T>& operator() (L(T::*f)(R...),R...r){
    a.f(r...);
    return *this; //returning reference to current wrap object.
  }
  T a;
};
```

A test class to accumulate numbers.

```
class testClass {
    int m;
public:
testClass(int _m) : m{_m}{}
    int f(int x) {
        m += x;
        std::cout << ' ' << m;
        return m;
    }
};
```

An usage example:

```
int main(){
  wrap<testClass> a{0};
  a(&testClass::f,13)(&testClass::f, 11)(&testClass::f,3)(&testClass::f, 21);
}
```

Output of sum accumulated at each step:

> 13 24 27 48

Comment: Probably you falsely assume that result type has the same type as base class.

Comment: @Logman No. Could you clarify what do you mean? Ther `operato()` returns a `wrap<T>&` so that we can call `operator()` on the return type again.

Comment: testClass::f returns int that means he want to wrap result like this wrap<int> not wrap<testClass>. Actually he point that in his question: "It's working (gcc, c++0x). But when I replace the 6,7th line with the following (to actually wrap the result) ...". In his code L parameter is important not T